# How to compute bounding box after using ObjLoader three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm running into an issue trying to get the bounding box of the geometry of a model after it is loaded with the OBJLoader. So far I have:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load( mURL, function ( object ) {

for ( var i = 0, l = object.children.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
    geometry = object.children[0].geometry;         
    bBox = geometry.computeBoundingBox();
    console.log("have a box of "+bBox);
}
//...rest of function
```

But the bBox is undefined when I write it to the console. Is geometry not the right property to access in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think something like this should do the trick:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load( mURL, function ( object ) {

    THREE.SceneUtils.traverseHierarchy( object, function ( child ) {

        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

            child.geometry.computeBoundingBox();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks mrdoob. That got me headed in the right direction. I had to do some more digging within the obj to get to the geometry. Check out my answer new answer.

Comment: Yes that's more efficient than my loop. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

This answer combines the last for the newest version of THREE.js

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load( mURL, function ( object ) {
object.traverse(function ( child ) {
    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
        child.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
        object.bBox = child.geometry.boundingBox;//<-- Actually get the variable
    }
});
};
```

Now you can access the dimensions of the mesh by typing object.bBox.max.x to get x for instance.

Answer (score 1):

@mrdoob's answer was correct but due to three.js API changes (as of r52), it should look like this now:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load( mURL, function ( object ) {
    object.traverse(function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            child.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on mrdoob's traverse function, I was able to get to a bounding box with the following:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load( mURL, function ( object ) {
    THREE.SceneUtils.traverseHierarchy(object, function(child){
    if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
        for (var i in child) {
            if(i == "geometry"){
                var geo = child[i];
                    geo.computeBoundingBox();
                    var bBox = geo.boundingBox;
                }
             }
         }
      });
      ///rest of loading function here
 });
```